# PlasticSCM - Icon 'unknown' not present in theme

Tags: gtk, centos7, plasticscm

I'm using CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708, Gnome 3.22.2 and I've installed PlasticSCM 6.0.16.1792.

I created a new repository and everything worked fine until I use the Workspace explorer or the  Pending changes tabs (only when changes exists). Plastic shows several error pop-ups with the message:

> Icon 'unknown' not present in theme

I've checked the logs in ${HOME}/.plastic4/gtkplastic.log.txt:

```
2017-12-04 16:43:15,252 (null) user at (null) ERROR ExceptionHandler - [HandleUnhandledGLibException] Unexpected error: Icon 'unknown' not present in theme.
```

I tried to change the icon theme from Adawait to Gnome using the Gnome Tweak Tool with no success.

Is there anything that I should configure to fix this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using pretty much the same setup and works for me. I installed from the latest iso at https://www.centos.org/download/:

**Centos 7.4.1708**:

```
> cat /etc/*elease
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)
```

**gnome 3.22.2**:

```
> cat /usr/share/gnome/gnome-version.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gnome-version>
 <platform>3</platform>
 <minor>22</minor>
 <micro>2</micro>
 <distributor>GNOME.Org</distributor>
 <date>2017-08-06</date>
```

**Plastic version 6.0.16.1820** (Latest available as I write)

```
cm version
6.0.16.1820
```

**This is what I have in the theme directory**:

```
> ls -l -R /opt/plasticscm5/theme/*
http://txt.do/dqve8
```

Can you try changing your OS icon set?

Comment: I've changed the icon twice and I'm still having the same problem. I have listed my files as well in the following paste:  

https://pastebin.com/yXEtitF8

Comment: I removed it and installed again. It still happening with the new version 6.0.16.1820-1.1

Comment: Apparently I fixed. I installed Xfce using 

`sudo yum groupinstall -y "Xfce`

this package contains **gnome-icon-theme-legacy.noarch**. 

Then, I tried Xfce successfully, then I changed the desktop to Gnome it worked as well and then the one that I was using Gnome classic.

Comment: Curiously, removing Xfce doesn't affect the gnome-icon-theme and after checking the dependencies of that package using repoquery --requires, it only shows gnome-icon-theme.

Comment: It seems for some reason I'm not needing that package, this is what I have:

Comment: [codice@localhost ~]$ yum list installed | grep gnome-icon-theme
gnome-icon-theme.noarch                    3.12.0-1.el7                anaconda
gnome-icon-theme-extras.noarch             3.12.0-1.el7                anaconda
gnome-icon-theme-symbolic.noarch           3.12.0-2.el7                anaconda

Comment: I've added this as a solution as the problem seems that I needed to change the icon set. However, it seems it installed Gnome without the legacy icons. I can not reproduce the error again, so I assume it would work only changing icons. Thanks.